# How to make ng-repeat filter more smoother

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

i am using ng-animate with ng-repeat.
The elements that appear and disappear are happening smoothly, but the case where some elements disappear, and the remainging elements are moving to the left is taking place abruptly.

How do i smoothen the movement of the left over elements ?

Do ask for more explanation if the requirement is not clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when binding a lot of data.

I found this plugin incredibly useful and lightweight: http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

I would definitely recommend it. It hugely improved initial page load times too.